# Protobuf and Pbjson on unsigned overflows

Tags: c++, json, protocol-buffers

This question is about `Pbjson` https://github.com/yinqiwen/pbjson and `Protobuf`, and how they interpret overflows in unsigned integers.
Consider the following message:

```
  message Foo {
    optional uint32 bar = 1;
  }
```

I then try to decode the following string:
`"{"bar": -1}"`
from `string` to `json` and then as a Proto-message.
Previously, Pbjson's `jsonobject2pb` used to throw an exception
due to `-1` being not an unsigned integer. After I updated
the `Pbjson` and `Protobuf` versions however, this value of `-1` is
being reinterpeted as `4294967295`.
Is there any commit to the above libraries that changed this behaviour?

Comment: It would help if you can tell what version used to throw an exception, and what version you are using now. Though I think you could just `git bisect` it yourself. The difference is likely to be in pbjson code.